# Find the area of rhombus $ABCD$

Tags: geometry

This is a problem for homework that I was stuck on.
$ABCD$ a rhombus. If G is the intersection point of diagonals of $ABCD$, find the area of $ABCD$.

[image]

So far, I've only drawn the line $GA$ and found that it was $12$ but I haven't been able to find anything else. I know that all sides are equal because it's a rhombus, but I'm not sure how to apply that to find more lengths. Can someone give me a hint without giving me the solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you draw $BD$?  What do you know about the angle at which the diagonals of a rhombus intersect?

Comment: I've rolled back your edit, because we need to see your diagram to understand the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Note that $GA=12, GE=6, \angle EGA=60$ implies that $\triangle GAE$ is $30-60-90$.

Comment: Well, rigorously, you can use the law of cosines to show that $\angle GAE=30$, hence it is a right angle by triangle sum law.

Comment: Sure, consider the 30-60-90 triangle with sides $6,6\sqrt{3},12$. Note that this triangle is congruent by $SAS$. Done :)